# Python send request, check response codes

Tags: python, request, base64

Total python newbie here,

I'm trying to create my script where i have encoded base64 string which i want to pass into get parameter in url and see response codes where 200 = succcess, 302 = failure.

I'm stucked at point how to make this GET request with my base64 string encoded.
I'm sure my code could be written way simple.

```
import string
import base64
from random import *
min_char = 352
max_char = 352
allchar = string.ascii_lowercase + string.digits
base64d = "".join(choice(allchar) for x in range(randint(min_char, max_char)))
data = base64.b64encode(base64d)
print data
```

I want to make request:

https://example.com/test.php?test=(base64d)

response codes 200 = succcess (show only in terminal), 302 = failure (don't show)

with ability to set how many threads.

keep running until 200 is hit.

Comment: try https://docs.python.org/2/library/httplib.html?

Comment: See http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/